# How to connect html pages using href method

Tags: html, css

`I am making a websites using separate pages. i don't know how to connect and link them.

I don't know what to do. I tried making a link method but it did not work.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

```
<href link="BotanicalGardens.html">
<href link="buyFlowers.html">
<href link="buyOther.html">
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, would you mind posting the code you used that didn't work? I'll take a look and see what I can do to help you if you just do that.

Comment: yep show us your code we will hep you as well as we can

Comment: you mean using `<a href="url">link text</a>` ? please provide a [mre] with more detail of your code to find out what you are tryind to do

Comment: I edited my answer below. It looks like you are using "href" as a tag instead of an attribute. Use "a" as the tag and let me know how that works.

Comment: This might assist you, the specification https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: I think this will help you in understanding hyperlinking in HTML : 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

After seeing your code, you are using "href" instead of "a" and "link" instead of "href" for your path. Try swapping those out and see if that works. See the below example.

```
<a href="BotanicalGardens.html">Link Text</a>
<a href="buyFlowers.html">Link Text</a>
<a href="buyOther.html">Link Text</a>
```

Before seeing your code, I can say that if you are just looking to make a link to another page, it is done like this:

```
<a href="path/to/your/page.html">Your Link Text Here</a>
```

If you have questions about the path thing, let me know, that is likely what is tripping you up.

[How to make a link internal and external](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: For sure! It wasn't too long ago that I was there. Keep asking questions, you'll figure it out!

Comment: @KevinAaronJeyasingh if this worked for you would you mind marking it as correct?